# Inconsistent behavior when parsing numbers from stringstream on different platforms

Tags: c++, ios, gcc, stringstream

In a project i'm using a stringstream to read numeric values using the operator>>. I'm now getting reports indicating that the parsing bahaviour is inconsistent across different platforms if additional characters are appended to the number (for instance "2i"). Compiling the sample below with GCC/VCC/LLVM on Linux results in:

val=2; fail=0

Compiling and running it on iOS with either GCC or LLVM reportedly yields:

val=0; fail=1

What does the standard say about the behavior of operator>> in such a case?

--- Sample Code ---------------------------------------------

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char **args)
{
  double val;
  std::stringstream ss("2i"); 
  ss >> val;
  std::cout << "val=" << val << "; fail=" << ss.fail() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

[image]

Thus, in either case:

- if your compiler is pre C++11 and reading fails it would leave the value of `val` intact and flag `failbit` with 0.
- if you compiler is post C++11 and reading fails it would set the value of `val` equal to 0 and flag `failbit` with 0.
- However, `operator>>`extracts and parses characters sequentially with function [`num_get::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/num_get/get/) [*27.7.2.2.2 Arithmetic extractors*], from the stream as long as it can interpret them as the representation of a value of the proper type.
- Thus, in your case `operator>>` will call `num_get::get` for the first character (i.e., `2`) and the reading will succeed, then it will move on to read the next character (i.e., `i`). `i` doesn't fit a numerical value and consequently `num_get::get` will fail and reading will stop. However, there are already valid characters been read. These valid characters will be processed and assigned to `val`, the rest of the characters will remain in the `stringstream`. To illustrate this I'll give an example:

---

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char **args)
{
  double val(0.0);
  std::stringstream ss("2i");
  
  ss >> val;
  
  std::cout << "val=" << val << "; fail=" << ss.fail() << std::endl;
  
  std::string str;
  ss >> str;
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> val=2; fail=0
>
> i

- You see that if I use extract operator again to a `std::string`, the character `i` is extracted.
- The above however, doesn't explain why you don't get the same behaviour in ios.

Comment: Unfortunately this section does not state whether the extraction is supposed to fail in this case. Do you have an idea whether the standard mandates that is has to fail? For instance if you take atof the documentation states it takes as many characters as possible according to a valid floating point syntax and reads those characters only. This is what appears to happen here on linux/windows it is not what happens on iOS even if the same compilers are used.

Comment: @user3701935 I don't think that it is related to OS but rather to compiler versions. I'll try to find if/where the standard has anything about this.

Comment: After reading the reference this is what i found out: The conversion is supposed to be done with strtold (C++11). strtold/strtod is supposed to read as much characters as possible until an invalid character is found. If I interpret this correctly the string "2i" should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with libc++ that was submitted to [**Bugzilla**](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17782). The problem as I see it is with [`std::num_get::do_get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get)'s `double` overload somehow continuing to parse the characters `a, b, c, d, e, f, i, x, p, n` and their captial equivalents despite those being invalid characters for an integral type (other than `e` where it denotes scientific notation but must be followed by a numeric value otherwise failure). Normally `do_get()` would stop when it finds an invalid character and not set `failbit` as long as characters were sucessfully extracted (as explained above).